# Android Studio - MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I'm new into the world of Android Studio. I did a basic app with somes buttons and now i'm trying to do something more complexe: Pressing a button call a service to record a video (with MediaRecorder) in the background and pressing it again will stop the recording.
Actually it run well but when i press the button for the second time (to stop the recording) it crash (E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007).
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main     Process: com.example.test4, PID: 27039     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.example.test4.MyRecIntentService@9dc2fc9: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.`
It create a mp4 file with a different size each time so i'm, assuming it's recording something. But each file is unreadable.

So i'm stuck and no forums on internet helped me atm. I even tried chatGPT, he's usefull to debug sometimes, but this time he wasn't. So if anyone can help me here, i'll be really grateful.
Thanks anyway for you time if you're passing by :). Have a nice day.

(I'm using an Huawei Mate 10 Pro - 'Device Manager' show 'Android 10.0')

Here's my code:

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test4"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <service
            android:name=".MyRecIntentService"
            android:exported="false"
        />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Test4.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
    boolean isRecording = false;
    Activity homeActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
     setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        homeActivity = this;

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(homeActivity, MyRecIntentService.class);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isRecording) {
                    binding.fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));

                    stopService(serviceIntent);
                } else {
                    binding.fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));

                    //Appelle le service Record Video
                    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "RECORDING =)", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();


                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
                        } else {
                            startService(serviceIntent);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "NO PERMISSIONS", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(homeActivity, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
                    }
                }
                isRecording = !isRecording;
            }
        });
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

    for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public class MyRecIntentService extends Service {
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private String mVideoFileName;
    private File mVideoFolder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        isRecording = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //Create dir
        createVideoFolder();

        //Create File
        try {
            createVideoFileName();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Media Recorder
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        try {
            setupMediaRecorder();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        startRecording();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        // Create a notification channel for Android Oreo and higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_id", "My Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        // Create the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel_id")
                .setContentTitle("My Service")
                .setContentText("Service is running in the foreground")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true);

        return builder.build();
    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 640);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);//270 si  mTotalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        startForeground(1, createNotification());

        mediaRecorder.start();

        isRecording = true;
    }

    private void createVideoFolder() {
        //File movieFile = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        //File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        mVideoFolder = new File(movieFile, "REC");
        if(!mVideoFolder.exists()) {
            mVideoFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private File createVideoFileName() throws IOException {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String prepend = "REC_" + timestamp + "_";
        File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", mVideoFolder);
        mVideoFileName = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return videoFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (isRecording) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        }
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        super.onDestroy();
        stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...    (==> second button clic)
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
I/MediaRecorder: stop
E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
I/BlockMonitor: dispatchingThrewException In MainThread
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] create disable file for com.example.test4 uid is 10025
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test4, PID: 30901
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.example.test4.MyRecIntentService@ad443c8: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:5002)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2491)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1916)
        at com.example.test4.MyRecIntentService.onDestroy(MyRecIntentService.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4982)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:260) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2491) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30901 SIG: 9
```